# How to sync Keychain passwords between iOS and macOS?

Tags: macos, ios, keychain

I'd like to share passwords between macOS and iOS. I've enabled iCloud keychain, moved all relevant passwords in Keychain App to iCloud but for some reason they don't appear in my iPhone. I check my passwords and there's nothing there. How can I debug this?

Comment: From where are you checking your passwords on iOS?

Comment: @abc  "Passwords & Accounts"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only passwords stored via Safari are synced between devices. Passwords manually added to Keychain App are not sent to iOS.

Comment: Yes seems like we need to add passwords in Mac via Safari > Preferences > Passwords in order for it to appear in iOS. That way it'll appear in Keychain too (not vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

Keychain must be turned on in both iOS and macOS. While data is moved back-and-forth through iCloud, data is not accessible *from* iCloud and need not (and should not) be moved manually from a computer or device into the user's iCloud storage. You can see Apple's directions for iOS [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208681), and for macOS [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208682). A good long-form discussion of Keychain synching is [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/apples-icloud-keychain-the-smart-persons-guide/). Apple's iOS page notes that Keychain synching is not available in all countries.

Briefly:

1. Turn on Keychain synching on your iPhone in Settings > iCloud > Keychain. The Keychain slider must be "On." (This is iOS 12.2; your iOS may vary.)
2. Turn on Keychain synching on your Mac in System Preferences > iCloud > Keychain. The checkbox next to "Keychain" must be checked.
3. Confirm that both the iPhone and the Mac are signed in to iCloud.

You don't need to manually move files; it all happens seamlessly behind the scenes.

Comment: so Keychain only applies to Safari usernames and passwords?

Comment: I think that Safari is the only browser that Keychain works with, but Keychain can also store credit card info. The Wikipedia article on Keychain says: *A Keychain can contain various types of data: passwords (for websites, FTP servers, SSH accounts, network shares, wireless networks, groupware applications, encrypted disk images), private keys, certificates, and secure notes.*

Comment: I'm adding passwords manually because I use Firefox. It's those passwords I can't sync between iOs and macOS.

Comment: You can visit Apple's walled garden with non-Apple visitors, but they're not allowed to use all Apple's tools.

Comment: I thought that since passwords are kept in Keychain, passwords added to Keychain would automagically sync to iOS. I guess Dashlane it is then.

Comment: It's a good theory. While one can add keychain items manually to various Keychains in the Keychain Access app File > New... selections, I'm not confident that even if added, new items would be autofilled in non-Apple browsers.

Comment: I don't care about autofill, I just want them to appear in iOS so I don't have to remember them.

Comment: I don't know the answer. Create one manually in Keychain on the Mac, and see if it shows up in iOS.

Comment: That's it, it doesn't.